# How to automate Puppet's modules install

Tags: ubuntu, deployment, puppet, continuous-delivery

I am working on one-click deployment of a system onto Ubuntu machine. Just started using Puppet for this. It appears, in order for me to use external modules, I must pre-install them using something like

```
puppet module install foo
```

Questions:

1. Do I always have to pre-install modules in order for me to use them?
2. How do I automate Puppet modules installation?

It's a standalone puppet set up (so not a master-slave one). I will have to repeat this many times for different customers. Hence will be nice to have a single button doing *all the* work for me. In later stage, there is a place for master-slave setup. But it must be independent for each customer though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question.

> **Do I always have to pre-install modules in order for me to use them?**

No, I don't. In a single node set up (masterless) the modules can be put into the `--modulepath=/my-module-root` path and puppet will pick them up. My problem was that the folder name for the module, did not match the class in the `init.pp`. For example

```
| modules
| -- gini_cassandra   ++ HERE ++
| ---- manifests
| ------ init.pp
```

Inside `init.pp` I had

```
class cassandra ...
```

Once I renamed `gini_cassandra` to `cassandra` things started working.

> **How do I automate Puppet modules installation?**

As I don't need to `install` the modules in a masterless setup, I don't need to automate it. However, I found `librarian-puppet` (thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21159849/706456)) to be really useful. I don't need to version-control external modules. Librarian will pull them for me on both my machine, target machine where I run installation, and on the build machine.

Answer (score 7):

I'm working in a master less setup.

You should probably look at [librarian-puppet](https://github.com/rodjek/librarian-puppet)
You write Puppetfile describe all your modules :

- local directory,
- remote git,
- puppet forge

and librarian-puppet will compute a modules directory for you.

```
librarian-puppet install
```

You can then upload it to the target machine and launch the puppet apply. 
It works well with vagrant also.

```
config.vm.provision :puppet, :module_path => "modules"
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but I found librarian-puppet really useful. It also works on Windows, which is my dev platform. Thumb up for the help. I will mark my own answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a puppet master then you only need to install modules on the master.  Client machines will not need them since the master will compile their config for them.

So if there's a module you want to use, a 1 time 'puppet module install foo' on the master is all that's required.

Comment: Make sense. In my set up, however, it's a single puppet node. I have to repeat this many times, for each customer. Is there any way to exclude manual step of `puppet module install foo`?

Comment: Create a puppet class that installs them with exec resources?